# Upload any file to ipython notebook directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have the following line on the notebook home page:

```
To import a notebook, drag the file onto the listing below or click here.
```

When I upload a text or any other file, I get an error message:

```
Invalid file type
Uploaded notebooks must be .ipynb files
```

How do I make it possible to upload any file ?
Is there any setting/ add on that will allow this?

Comment: the notebooks are in [json format](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/nbconvert.html#notebook-format) and so must be formatted like so with .ipynb suffix you can't load any text file of arbitrary format

Answer (score 0):

This is now implemented on **master** (futur 3.0), we now have the content webservice which can deal with non-ipynb file. Just drag file onto the dashboard and it works(tm).

Keep in mind that this upload on the machine were the webserver is, not the machines were the kernels run in case they are not the same.